# How to enable hyperlinks in grid

Tags: microstrategy

I have a document that contains a grid (Among others).
One column in the grid has full hyperlinks leading to a ticketing system, i.e.

https://ticketsystem.internal.company.com/tickets/ticket1337

I want to enable users to click on the URL and open the ticket in a new browserwindow.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the url is an attribute form, if you right click on the column header you should be able to create the link (below the example in web, but it works similarly also in Developer).

[image]

Comment: turns out the attribute needs html tags to be a clickable URL and that is done in the data model. 
The "edit links" is still a nice feature I didn't know about, thank you for that :)

Comment: if you are linking outside MicroStrategy go for the tag, if you are linking another MicroStrategy object better the link functionality

Answer (score 0):

The attribut needs to be formatted with HTML tags to be a clickable link, using  to encapsule the URL-string.
This is done in the data model.